# Unable to remove form elements while using element.parentNode.removeChild(element)

Tags: javascript, element, removechild

I have a form that will submit to a Google search appliance, forming a query string "q".

In the form I have radio buttons and a hidden element; the radio buttons contain options for sites to select; the hidden element contains multiple sites that will allow the user to select multiple site searches.

```
<input type="radio" id="site_search" name="as_sitesearch" value="www.mycompany.com" checked>Current site<br />
<input type="radio" id="site_search" name="as_sitesearch" value="archive.mycompany.com">Archive site<br />
<input type="radio" id="site_search" name="as_sitesearch" value="">Both sites<br />
<input type="hidden" id="as_oqOption" name="as_oq" value="www.mycompany.com archive.mycompany.com">
```

This is the Javascript I wrote that will remove the radio element or the hidden element exclusively (one of them can exist in the form submittal):

```
// IF THE USER CHECKED "BOTH SITES", YOU WILL HAVE TO WIPE OUT THE VALUE OF as_sitesearch TO ALLOW FOR PASSING OF as_oq FOR GOOGLE ENGINE
if (form.elements['as_sitesearch'][0].value.length == 0) {
        var goodbyeElement = document.getElementById('site_search');
        goodbyeElement.parentNode.removeChild(goodbyeElement);
} else {
        var goodbyeElement = document.getElementById('as_oqOption');
        goodbyeElement.parentNode.removeChild(goodbyeElement);
}
```

However, when the form is submitted, "q" winds up obtaining both radio and hidden elements no matter what radio option I click.

Not sure why this is happening as I followed the guides in the DOM tutorial sites I have read on how to remove a form element prior to submittal.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple elements can't share the same ID.

Comment: Thanks, I made the requested changes to the IDs, unfortunately, the same problem persists.. both radio and hidden elements exist in the form submittal at the same time, even though one or the other should have been destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you:

```
   (form.as_sitesearch[2].checked){
         for(var k=0; k<form.as_sitesearch.length;k++){
            form.as_sitesearch[k].parentNode.removeChild(form.as_sitesearch[k])
        }
    }
   else{
        var goodbyeElement = document.getElementById('as_oqOption');
        goodbyeElement.parentNode.removeChild(goodbyeElement);    
   }
```

You should call it on form submit. here form is document.form[index];

Comment: I wrote that code already, however, it fails to function as both radio and hidden elements are passed, ignoring the entire conditional

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Apparently form.elements will always fail because of the grouping, so don't use it..

```
// IF THE USER CHECKED "BOTH SITES", YOU WILL HAVE TO WIPE OUT THE VALUE OF as_sitesearch TO ALLOW FOR PASSING OF as_oq FOR GOOGLE ENGINE
if (document.getElementById('site_search3').checked) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            eval('var goodbyeElement = document.getElementById("site_search' + i + '");');
            goodbyeElement.parentNode.removeChild(goodbyeElement);
        }
} else {
        var goodbyeElement = document.getElementById('as_oqOption');
        goodbyeElement.parentNode.removeChild(goodbyeElement);
}
```